# Footer widget is disabled when using add_filter method

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using the following code for using PHP in a WordPress widget. The PHP code is complete and running as expected but my footer widget is still disabled.

```
function php_execute($html) {
    if (strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false) {
        ob_start(); eval("?".">".$html);
        $html=ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter('widget_text','php_execute',100);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?? This looks like a bad idea...

Comment: I have corrected a few typo errors and grammar mistakes in the title and content.